# How to create a pluginable application using dart?

Tags: plugins, dart

I would like to know how could I create a pluginable application using dart. I read about `defered imports`, but I'm still not able to join the points and create the app. I know for java exist `OSGi`, so I'm looking for something similar. As another example it should be something similar to wordpress plugins.

Comment: You can load a plugin as isolate

Comment: Also a Plugin can mean a lot. If you add a plugin statically you can load it in the same isolate. Your question doesn't say anything about what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I mean having 2 separate projects, one will be the plugin manager and the second the plugin. Then I'll start the plugin manager and whenever a user upload a zip file containing the code of the plugin (second project) then the plugin manager (first project) runs the code of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to synchronously load and execute arbitrary code in Dart. You could use Isolates and define some sort of protocol, or use any other sort of (asynchronous) RPC mechanism.